# After loging out from the welcome page and refreshing the homepage, it's redirect to the welcome page

Tags: php, logout

After loging in from the homepage and loging out from the welcome page, refreshing the site redirect me to the welcome page.

i'am running MySQL on alfahosting.de server

i've used the `unset($_SESSION)` but it's seems not working

```
session_start();

$error = "";

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)){

    unset($_SESSION);
    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE["id"] = "";

}else if((array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['id']) OR 
array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)){

header("Location: loggedinpage.php");

}
```

there are no error messages, only the redirecting from the homepage to the welcome page after loging out from welcomepage

Comment: And the actual expected behavior would be …? The code you have shown, is that a single script called only once, is it an include file embedded into every “page”, or - what? Please go read [ask], and provide us with a [mre] that properly shows what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to logout you have to destroy the session with

> [session_destroy ()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

I hope it helps you